# Can't get user's information after account linking by Auth0

Tags: google-oauth, google-smart-home

I follow [this site](https://medium.com/google-developers/authenticating-smart-home-actions-for-the-google-assistant-with-auth0-b6fda3d2ee3d) to build account linking.I can get access token by

```
const getEmail = async (headers) => {
  const accessToken = headers.authorization.substr(7);
  const {email} = await auth0.getProfile(accessToken);
  console.log('email',email);
  return email;
}
```

But when I want to get user email,I found my console Log had "undefined".

My goal is to get user's unique id and email.How can I do?

Update 1:
I try to use another method like below

```
var ManagementClient = require('auth0').ManagementClient;
var management = new ManagementClient({
    domain: 'domain.auth0.com',
    clientId: 'clientId',
    clientSecret: 'clientSecret',
    scope: 'read:users update:users'
});
...
management.getUsers(function(err, users) {
      if (err) {
        // handle error.
      }
      console.log('users1: ',users);
});
```

I can get cosole Log message(users) showed by JSON format.But it contain all of users who ever signed in.
(You can see as below that have two records.)

```
  [ { created_at: '',
    email: '',
    email_verified: true,
    family_name: '',
    given_name: '',
    identities: [ [Object] ],
    locale: 'zh-TW',
    name: '',
    nickname: '',
    picture: 'https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-M2k7RI6lLA8/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/ACHi3rcLWKHlBjbH9QBZxOvNEm1jxzuQiQ/photo.jpg',
    updated_at: '',
    user_id: 'google-oauth2|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    last_login: ',
    last_ip: '',
    logins_count: 15 },
  { created_at: '',
    email: '',
    email_verified: false,
    identities: [ [Object] ],
    name: '',
    nickname: '',
    picture: 'https://s.gravatar.com/avatar/a054eb742d33851c51da5944764d7fca?s=480&r=pg&d=https%3A%2F%2Fcdn.auth0.com%2Favatars%2Fwe.png',
    updated_at: '',
    user_id: 'auth0|zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz',
    last_login: '2',
    last_ip: '',
    logins_count: 1 } ]
```

What API can I use to get an user who is logining now?

Update2:
[login records](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5oU9.png)
I found that I can get user's email successfully if google smart home app pop out this page for me to enter account and secret.
Like below:
[login page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fbjhN.jpg)

Success record:
[Success record](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSRig.png)

But if app can't pop out login page for me to enter account and secret,I will fail to get user's email.
Fail record:
[Fail record](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7nKL.png)

Question is what can I set to let login flow normally so that I can get user's information successfully?

Comment: you probably need to request an email scope to get back email.  Check the documentation.

Comment: I found a problem that I could get the email who login from google smart home app when connect to device but sometimes it didn't pop out  the login screen.I mean if smart home app doesn't pop out login screen I can't get user's email.Why?

Comment: technically once your user has linked to their account it shouldn't need to log them in again.

Comment: I edit my question again.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the code, it looks like you’re not able to get through to the Smart Home steps yet. There is a high possibility of a bug in the code as it can be seen that two login methods have been implemented. One is through password and the other one is the Google signin method.

Try recreating the project and implement only one method at a time. If you’re still facing issues then please create an issue at http://issuetracker.google.com